# For which parameter p will the following series be convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin \frac{1}{n^p} $$

Well, as I know this is pretty similar to the Riemann zeta function, and as I checked this will be divergent if $p \leq 1$. And it will be convergent if $p>1$. How can I continue the problem solving?

Comment: Can you confirm whether you're looking only at positive $p$, or if negative $p$ is included?

Comment: the exercise tells nothing about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a partial answer.

Assuming $p>0$, so that $\displaystyle \frac{1}{n^p}\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, you can use the Limit Comparison Test to compare the given series with $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^p}$, whose behavior is well-known. That will give you that the series diverges for $0<p\le1$ and converges for $p>1$.

If $p=0$, then all terms of the series are constant $\sin1\neq0$, so the series obviously diverges.

But if $p<0$, then denoting $q=-p$, we are looking at the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin(n^q)$ with $q>0$. I believe that it diverges because $\sin(n^q)$ would oscillate, but right now of top of my head I can't come up with a proof. I have a feeling, though, that something like this has been asked here on Math.SE before …

Comment: Did you not read my solution, which was posted 8 minutes before yours?

Comment: @Dr.MV: ??? I fail to see the point of your question...

Comment: The hint already provided a way forward for $p>0$.  As for $p\le 0$, does the general term of the sequence $\sin(n^p)$ approach $0$?

Comment: @Dr.MV: And where in the Math.SE policies does it say that if Dr.MV posted an answer then nobody else is allowed to do so? Your hint is correct and it's a very good one for the case $p>0$ (as if I didn't understand that myself -- I did). But I still fail to see the relevance of your quarrel with me.

Comment: I have no quarrel with you.  You presumptuousness is offensive.  You're behavior is, therefore, a violation of MSE policy and I request now that you cease this chain of communication.  As for the math question that you raised ... Let's take the case $p=-1$.  If $\sin(n)\to 0$, then $\sin(n+1)=\sin(1)\cos(n)+\cos(1)\sin(n)\to 0$.  Which would mean that $\cos(n)\to 0$ also.  But $\cos^2(n)+\sin^(n)=1$ and cannot approach $0$.  Hence, $\sin(n)$ does not approach $0$.